# Javascript finding all strings that matches a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Can some one please tell me the approach how to find all the string that matches a pattern given in the pastebin?

http://pastebin.com/SmWP1usB

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try learning/using regular expression.

Comment: I know a little about regex, but if you be specific to solve the problem it would help. As I find it difficult to solve.

Comment: Try going through the tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html so you can learn how regular expressions work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer - [Regex Global Modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

For example,

```
var s = "Is this all there is?";
console.log(s.match(/is/g)); //alert(s.match(/is/g));
```

will match all instances of "is" in a string.

Unable to access pastebin from here, hope this helps.